# Laravel 4 & MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-4, php-mongodb

I'm a Laravel's fan. Php generally & Laravel individually is a good  combination with MySql. However, I have recently been interested in MongoDB's flexibility & simplicity. I want to refer your ideas about:

- Is the combination between Laravel & MongoDB good?
- Which package should I use? (Laravel-MongoDB, lmongo, mongolid-laravel...)
- Have you tried building apps with Laravel & Mongodb?

Thank all.

Comment: This would probably take a lot of time and testing and seems like it could be an application-specific question. If it works for you, use it!

Comment: This question may be better suited to the [Laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/), since questions on library opinions [are not well-suited](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for StackOverflow. You'll likely get more relevant responses on the forum as well.